# Exception: Sub-message not read correctly

Tags: c#, .net, exception, deserialization, protocol-buffers

During deserialization of a big file (20GB) in c# with protobuf-net I get a `"Sub-message not read correctly" Exception`. The Exception occur after reading 2 GB of 20 GB.
The same data-structure works with a smaller instance.

The serialization of the 20 MB data works fine.

Here is some example code for serialization:

```
            if (File.Exists(filename))
                File.Delete(filename);

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                Serializer.Serialize<HubLabelingData>(stream, data);
                stream.Close();
            }
```

Here is some example code for deserialization:

```
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                data = Serializer.Deserialize<HubLabelingData>(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }
```

Here is the Data Structure (works fine for small instances):

```
[ProtoContract]
public class HubLabelingData
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public HL[] hlf;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public HL[] hlb;

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public NG g;

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public List<PL> plf;

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public List<PL> plb;

    [ProtoMember(6)]
    public PHL[] pihlf;

    [ProtoMember(7)]
    public PHL[] pihlb;
}

[ProtoContract]
public class HL
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int[] l;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public double[] d;
}

[ProtoContract]
public class PL
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Dictionary<int, List<GP>> p;
}

[ProtoContract]
public class PHL
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public short[] l;
}

[ProtoContract]
public class NG
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public NA[] e;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public NA[] tne { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public float[] a;

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public float[] o;

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public int num = 0;

}

[ProtoContract]
public class NA
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int one { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int two { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public double tree { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public int four { get; set; }

}

[ProtoContract]
public class NN
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<NA> nas;

}

[ProtoContract]
public class GP
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public float one { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public float two { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Please post some example code

Comment: Do you need more example code?

Comment: @ditzel  You should show code of 'HubLabelingData' object.

Comment: I don't suppose you have a scenario or data file that I ca use to repro? I can try some random things to get a repeat, but it would be nicer to have an actual repro case.

Comment: I have a data file. But it's 20 GB. The Problem is to set it on a place to download. An other Serializer would solve my problem, too. But the BinaryFormatter e.g. took several hours to deserialize.

Comment: Is it one big Message ???; one other point 2GB is about MaxInteger so it could be related to using an int where a long is really needed.

Comment: Thanks. This hint leeds me to many posts, that protobuff .net can't handle files bigger than 2 GB. I think i have to split the data.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I have one.  It is 2.44 GB on disk and over 20GB in memory when it fails with this message.  I could put a copy on my web server, if you want to take a stab at fixing it?  It took me 14 hours to generate the model and I cannot seem to load it without this error :(

Comment: I upgraded to r668 with no luck.  However, I have not tried to recreate the model yet with r668, only load it into memory from disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone with the same problem:

Protbuf.net does not support deserializing files (respectively objects) larger than 2.048 GB.

I split the data into multiple messages. Was a lot more work, but it works perfekt.

Comment: I would always suggest using Multiple Delimited Message's rather than one huge message if you can

Comment: You mean 2,048 MB ?

Answer (score 0):

protobuf-net supports deserializing streams >2GB as of v2.2.0, with caveats.

Migrating from v2.0.0.668 to v2.3.13 fixed this issue for me, where previously I was getting the `"Sub-message not read correctly"` Exception.

[Release notes](https://mgravell.github.io/protobuf-net/releasenotes#v220)